# OpenCV Python: Occasionally get segmentation fault when using FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: python, opencv, surf, flann

I'm trying to classify objects using SURF and kNN. The code work well however it occasionally crashes and shows 'Segmentation Fault'. I'm not sure whether I did something wrong but I'm pretty sure that it is corrected. Here is the input file in case that you want to reproduce the issue.

[Link to download the dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4c6igslcse3ie5/Bank.zip?dl=0)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

trainfile = ['/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/15_20_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/15_50_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/15_100_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/15_500_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/15_1000_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/16_20_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/16_50_front.jpg'
            , '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/Training/16_500_front.jpg']
testfile = '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/20_1.jpg'

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

# Initiate FLANN matcher
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

# Initiate SURF detector
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(500)

# Create list of describtor
descriptor = []
for file in trainfile:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
    descriptor.append(des)

# Clasify using test file
img = cv2.imread(testfile)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kp1, des = surf.detectAndCompute(gray, None)

maxCount = 0
for i, d in enumerate(descriptor):  
    matches = flann.knnMatch(d, des, k=2)

    count = 0

    # ratio test as per Lowe's paper
    for (m,n) in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
            count += 1

    if count > maxCount:
        maxCount = count
        maxMatch = i

print maxMatch
```

Before I wrote this code, I have tried to create a kNN model which contain every training data and do the match only once. However it always fail and cause segmentation fault at "flann.add(descriptors)".

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

trainfile = ['/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/100_1.jpg', '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/100_2.jpg', '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/100_3.jpg']
testfile = '/home/nuntipat/Documents/Dataset/Bank/100_1.jpg'

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

# Initiate FLANN matcher
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

# Initiate SURF detector
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

# Train FLANN
for file in trainfile:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    keypoints, descriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(gray, None)

    flann.add(descriptors)
```

Thanks you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

At the point that it fails, there probably is a blank image or an image with very few descriptors. The descriptor matrix is then empty and hence it fails.

Comment: I have checked it like this 'if d.size == 0 or des.size == 0' but the array is never empty.

Answer (score 1):

It says here in this link the following:

```
flann.add([descriptors])
```

http://answers.opencv.org/question/44592/flann-index-in-python-training-fails-with-segfault/

Hope it helps!