# Open CV Ubuntu Python (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: python, opencv, pattern-matching, sift

I am working with open cv 3.0.0 on Python 2.7. I am trying to detect logo by Surf method. But facing with an error that is segmentation fault. Could you please help us to solve this problem. This error is not always occurred. It appears sometimes. I am sharing codes below.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('logo1.jpg',0) # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('logo2.jpg',0) # trainImage
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 4)

search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(des1,np.float32),np.asarray(des2,np.float32),k=2)
        for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
            if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                c +=1

        return(c)
```

I think segmentation error appear at this line:

```
matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(des1,np.float32),np.asarray(des2,np.float32),k=2)
```

Comment: Do you have Python with debugging symbols and GDB? If so, you can use the debugger to identify what is causing the segfault: is it specific to the library or specific to a bug in your code that causes a segfault in the underlying C library.

Comment: Right now, there imply isn't enough information to help. What I would do is first identify exactly which line is the offending one (comment everything below a certain line, see if it runs, and if it does, uncomment another line and repeat). Once you've identified that, check to see if the image description is small:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583304/opencv-python-occasionally-get-segmentation-fault-when-using-flannbasedmatcher

Comment: I put print between each line and found error at this line : matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(des1,np.float32),np.asarray(des2,np.float32),k=2)